# Raspbian ROS Indigo - Rosserial_xbee error

Tags: ros, arduino, raspberrypi, raspbian, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I've been trying out the Xbee network tutorial from the wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_xbee/Tutorials/Example%20Network

My setup: Raspberry Pi with Xbee Series 1 and Arduino Uno with Wireless SD shield that has a Xbee Series 1 on top of that.

I have configured the Xbee's with XCTU and the xbee is connected to the AMA0 port

When I try to run the command: `rosrun rosserial_xbee xbee_network.py /dev/ttyAMA0 1` I can see the Arduino flashing as if it is sending the data. When i open Arduino's port monitor i can also see that it is sending the data. So i guess the Xbee connection isn't the problem here?

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run 
   self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 434, in run 
   if self.port.inWaiting() < 1:
AttributeError: FakeSerial instance has no attribute 'inWaiting'
```

I found only one other person struggling with the same problem here; http://answers.ros.org/question/187443/xbee-network-error/
But no obvious fix was found?
The marked answer suggests that installing ROS hydro rosserial fixes the problem. Can that actually work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206358/raspbian-ros-indigo---rosserial_xbee-error/) by [rip24](https://answers.ros.org/users/22043/rip24/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I posted an issue on the [github rosserial site](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/179)

***I have marked the Issue resolved***
Please visit the link above to see the solution.

---

Originally posted by [rmolin88](https://answers.ros.org/users/22045/rmolin88/) with karma: 26 on 2015-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rip24](https://answers.ros.org/users/22043/rip24/) on 2015-04-03**:
Thanks for the info, atleast now i know that this is an issue for everyone =)